# Find the transitive closure of a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

> Let the relation $R=\{(0,0),(0,3),(1,0),(1,2),(2,0),(3,2)\}$
>
> Find the $R'$ the transitive closure of R.

I honestly don't understand this question at all.  Am I being asked to first find $R'$ and then the transitive closure of $R$ given $R'$?

I'm not sure if my question makes sense, but appreciate any hints to solving this.

Comment: Hi, it seems that $R'$ is the notation of the transitive closure of $R$.

Comment: It means given $R$, find the transitive closure $R^*$. For example, $0\to 3$ and $3 \to 2$ are in $R$, so you must have $0 \to 2$ in $R^2$. Basically you repeat the closure process until the set stops changing, if that makes sense. In this case it might be easiest to compute by drawing a graph and adding edges appropriately.

Comment: @copper.hat so given the definition of transitive closure, I would find $R'$ by, for example, taking the pairs $(0,3),(1,0)$ and realizing my $R'$ requires there to be a $(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes. I added something (a little more abstractly) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R,S$ are relations, then define $RS$ (or $R \circ S$) as
$R \circ S = \{ (x,z) | \exists y \ xRy \text{ and } y S z\}$.
Let $R^k$ be the composition of $R$ with itself $k$ times.

Then define $R^* = \cup_{k=1}^\infty R^k$. Since $R$ above is finite, then one can explicitly compute $R^*$ in a finite number of steps by a 'fixed point'
computation starting with $R$.

By 'fixed point', I mean to find the smallest set $Q$ such that $R \subset Q$ and $RQ \subset Q$, and the scheme is $Q_0 = R$, $Q_{k+1}= Q_k \cup R Q_k$, stopping when $Q_{k+1} = Q_k$.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: If I may ask two questions. Is there a correspondence between the transitive closure of a set (i.e., repeated unions) and the transitive closure of a relation? And in calculating the transitive closure of a relation, as above, do you always end up the smallest set $Q$ no matter how you link things up? Thanks. With regards,

Comment: @Andrew: I am not sure what you mean by transitive closure of a set, you would need to give me an example (unions of what?). The scheme above will result in the smallest set satisfying $R \subset Q$ and $R Q \subset Q$.

Comment: Thanks. $TC(x)=\bigcup_{n\in\omega} TC_{n}(x)$ or $TC(x)=x\cup\bigcup x\cup\bigcup\bigcup x\cup\dots$. Or better described on page 49 here: https://www.math.ku.edu/~roitman/SetTheory.pdf.

Comment: II believe this corresponds to the relation $xRy$ **iff** $y = \cup x$.

Comment: Thanks, just saw this. It occurred to me that the TC of a relation reduces, as your description and others' show. Whereas the transitive closure is expansive: taking a set $S$ and showing its elements all the way down. Maybe it should be called the transitive "dis"closure.

Answer (score 2):

I think $R'$ is the transitive closure of $R$, to find the closure I recommend you draw the digraph of the relation, that is put point of the plane for each of the vertices and draw an arrow from $a$ to $b$ for each pair $(a,b)$ after this draw an arrow from $c$ to $d$ if you can get from $c$ to $d$ using the current arrows. Stop when you have done this for all vertices. The closure is the relation with the pairs $(a,b)$ which have an arrow from $a$ to $b$.