# How one can find the transitive closure of a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

I am trying to understand transitive closures but have a very hard time doing so. I have done some easy exercises but I am stuck on this one:
x = {<1,4>,<2,4>,<3,2>,<4,2>} what is the transitive closure of x. If someone would be so nice and give me a helping hand I would appreciate it.

Comment: "A hard transitive closure task, please help :)" is not an appropriate title, 1) because it is not "hard" and 2)  because "please help" is not to be in a title (otherwise, it should be in *every* title). I have taken the liberty to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a graph, in the sense of placing numbers 1,2,3,4 as towns anywhere and using an arrow (meaning a one way road) between $i$ and $j$ whenever ordered pair $\langle i, j \rangle$ is in the list.

[image]

Then add to the list any $\langle k, \ell \rangle$ such that there exist a road hopefully using 2 (or more, which is not the case here) arrows allowing to go from $k$ to $\ell$.

In the case at hand, you will have to add the following:

$\langle 1, 2 \rangle$, $\langle 3, 4 \rangle$

Added to the four initial ordered pairs, we have obtained the transitive closure.

Comment: why do you add  <2,1>?

Comment: @miracle173 My bad, Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1061934)